# how can we clear a default mock for next test

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Is there anyway we can clear out default mock for the next successvie test case, i have something in below fashion

```
jest.mock("./src/utils/ajaxHelper", () => {
  const mockNoop = () => new Promise(() => {});
  return {
    default: mockNoop,
    get: mockNoop,
    post: mockNoop,
    put: mockNoop,
    interceptors: {
      request: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
      response: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
    },
  };
});



describe("Login something", () => {
  it("first class", async () => {
 -->-->  mock should work 
  });

  it("Second class", async () => {
 -->-->  mock should be clear here  
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "next test"?

Comment: @slideshowp2 i meant next test case , i have edited the question